# Dynamic Form, PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to make a form where you can fill out fields as following:

PC Model,
PC Serial,
Software etc

and if they have more then one PC you could click add more and in the same table it would add and create the column pcmodel_2 or something along them lines and then display that in the view page for as many computers as they have had.

I have come up with the following that is no good as it don't do it on it's own, and was hoping for help on doing this a proper and more intelligent way.

edit.php

```
  <form action="add.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $row['firstname'] ?>">

  <?php if ($row['name'] == NULL){ }else {?>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
  <?php } ?>

  <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
</form>
```

add.php

```
 if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];

  // Update
  if ($firstname == NULL){
    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE users SET firstname='$firstname' WHERE id=$id");
  }else {
    mysqli_query($db,"ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN name varchar(255)");
    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE users SET name='$firstname' WHERE id=$id");
  };

  //GOTO
  header('location:index.php');
};
```

index.php

```
<?php
$count=1;
$sel_query="Select * from users ORDER BY id desc;";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr><td align="center"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["firstname"]; ?></td>

<td><?php if ($row['name'] == NULL){ echo "empty"; }else {
  echo $row['name'];
} ?></td>
```

This is a basic start to what I was trying to do.

Comment: It's a bit unclear where this is going. Associating multiple assets to one user could be done through an 1:N mapping table. Your excerpts seem to be about the user listing part only at the moment. Perhaps take this to a help forum first ([/r/phphelp](https://old.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/)), or else post something more isolated to adapt. // The only advise you'll gonna get here is: read up on parameter binding / and let mysqli_ die already.

Answer (score 1):

there is a lot to be changed here. I'll just point them out with brief examples but you should take your time studying and practicing.

### First: ER Design

Your application shouldn't be altering your database scheme while it works, altering databases is something we do when we change our entity relationship design, so what you need here actually is a data normalization process.

roughly, as for this case, you should have two tables the first is for users as:

```
id  | user
--- | ---
1   | user1
2   | user2
```

another table to record all users assets:

```
id| user_id | asset
--|---------|------
1 | 1       | Machine belongs to user 1
2 | 1       | Peripheral belongs to user 1
3 | 2       | Machine belongs to user 2
```

in both tables, id field value called *Primary key*, while in second table we call user_id field value *Parent Key* which refers to the user record which related to the asset.

### Second: UI Front End

adding more elements is actually common feature being implemented (usually) with JavaScript, which you can create an array of input (not a real array but simulating them) as in the following example:

```js
function add() {
  var divApp = document.getElementById("app");
  var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
  divApp.appendChild(inputElement);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button onclick="add()">+</button>
</div>
```

### Third: SQL injection

For real life application there are many issues such code will be prone to, *sql injection attack* is one of the most common attacks that can be result of concatenating input variables into sql statement the way you did, to prevent them you should always use [escaping functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain Ahmed, Am i right in saying If i did two tables called computers and people and joined them like so

$id=$_GET['id']; 
$query=mysqli_query($db,"select * from computer, people WHERE pcid ='$id' and pcid = id"); 
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

How would I make the form for laptop 2 (computer row 2) and add the row in computer (table2) link to people (table 1)

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: you are most welcome, to represent the result, you got one row in peoples' table that is joined to many rows from computers' table, here you can read more about [joining tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) it gets confusing sometimes but with trail and practice you get the correct result you need (one table with users and their machines).

Answer (score 0):

SubmitDatabase Connection

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "companyprofile");
Update Data in Databaseif(!empty($_POST['des'])){$des=$_POST['des'];
$updquery=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE profile SET des ='$des' WHERE id = 1");
if($updquery) { echo "Company Profile has been Successfully Updated";}
else{echo "Updated Failed";}}
?>
```